# Prevent Directory.GetFiles() from searching short file names

Tags: vb.net, file, pattern-matching, filenames, wildcard

Let's say I have a directory 'C:\Test' with three files in it:

```
A23456789.txt
A1.txt
G 5.txt
```

And I run this command:

```
Dim FileArr = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Test", "*1.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

All three files are returned.

I understand that this is by design and .NET searches the 8.3 short file names as well.
But is there any way to override this and search the actual file names only?

Surely, in this day and age there must be a function to do this. Or do I have to write my own?
I would like the search function to have the same behavior as the Windows Explorer for consistency.

Comment: Add a file named "foo.txtbar" to see that wildcards have outlived their usefulness.

Comment: Windows Explorer is not confused by this, only the GetFiles() function. It seems the function's matching feature is obsolete. What is a good replacement for wildcards from a user's perspective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses LINQ:

```
Dim FileArr = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Test", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories). _
    Where(Function(s) s Like "*1.txt")
```

Comment: The `Like` operator doesn't always produce the same results as the Windows Explorer, which is what most users are most familiar with. But I guess it is the best we can do, short of trying to implement the Explorer algorithm ourselves. BTW, is the algorithm published anywhere?

Comment: On the bright side, playing around with the `Like` operator led me to discover a bug. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971777/possible-bug-in-vb-net-like-operator

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach would be to remove the filter from `GetFiles` and filter it out with LINQ, where you have a little more control:

```
Dim FileArr = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Test", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Dim filtered = From f In FileArr Where Path.GetFileName(f).EndsWith("1.txt")
```

Or some equivalent.

Comment: Thank you. I've never used LINQ before. Does it have the same support for wildcards as Windows Explorer?

Comment: @mcu If you've never used LINQ (Language INtegrated Query) before, take a look at the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx) to learn more. LINQ is a very powerful querying / filtering construct. It can query / filter any collection, not just files.