# Possible bug in VB.NET 'Like' operator?

Tags: .net, vb.net, wildcard, string-matching, sql-like

Why is it that the following evaluates as `True`?

```
Dim result = "b" Like "*a*b"
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
To generalize this a bit, the following returns `True`:

```
"String1" Like "*AnyText1*AnyText2*AnyText???******????*String1"
```

VBA works correctly, returning `False`.
PowerShell works correctly, returning `False`:

```
PS C:\Users\XXX> "b" -Like "*a*b"
False
```

EDIT2:
The link to the bug report:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748415/a-bug-in-net-like-operator

Comment: Are you sure? That returns `False` in Visual Basic. Surely it's the same in VB.NET.

Comment: Yep, I am sure. It is different in VB6/VBA?

Comment: I can confirm that the result is `False` in VBA.

Comment: Wow.  From what I can tell, you've actually found a legit bug.  `Dim result = "b" Like "*wsdfgsdfg*b"` returns True as well.

Comment: It looks that way to me. (`"This part needs to match" Like "*Put anything you want here.*This part needs to match"`) also returns true.

Comment: mono-2.4.2.3 [returns False](http://ideone.com/fauMv)

Comment: I'm definitely going with 'bug'; this also does not match the SQL Server LIKE nor the PowerShell -like operators. File it on connect? (Concidentally -- this isn't the first bug in the VB.NET LIKE operator to be reported.)

Comment: @Konrad .NET version 3.5

Comment: Cool. Looks like you found a real bug. I can find nothing in the MSDN documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) to explain this behavior.

Comment: looking at the "like" code with ilspy is interesting, I think I know why this bug exist

Comment: @mcu - in case you still need the functionality, you could use a regex. "^(.*)a(.*)b$"

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Connect. I will let you know if I hear anything.

Comment: @Cyborgx37, so look at my answer, I think I found the  bug :-)

Comment: @mcu, can you post the link of the bug report?

Comment: bug report is https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748415/a-bug-in-net-like-operator#tabs and i added my answer to the comment section

Comment: not sure but maybe you should change the tag to .net without vb.net since you can call that like operator from c#, who would not idea but still can do it Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LikeOperator.LikeString("string", "Pattern","Method");

Comment: Your question has at least `5` votes for the [tag:like-operator] tag. Could I kindly request that you suggest [tag:sql-like] as a [synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/like-operator/synonyms)?

Answer (score 6):

I decided, for fun, to open up ilspy to debug this :-)

in this method;

```
    private static void MatchAsterisk(string Source, int SourceLength, int SourceIndex, LigatureInfo[] SourceLigatureInfo, string Pattern, int PatternLength, int PatternIndex, LigatureInfo[] PattternLigatureInfo, ref bool Mismatch, ref bool PatternError, CompareInfo Comparer, CompareOptions Options)
```

for this condition

```
                if (SourceLength <= 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
```

by changing it to

```
                if (SourceLength < 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
```

it seem to be make it work as intended

I only did a few small test, nothing big

the issue is; it is only looking at the LAST asterisk and when it was valid, was stopping right there

my small change make sure to check the previous one, or anything in fact before it

with my fix

```
 Dim result = "b" Like "*a*b"
 now return false

 "String1" Like "*AnyText1*AnyText2*AnyText???******????*String1"
 now return false
```

but does return true when it need to return true